# Failed to start Apache Web Server

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, archlinux

I'm trying to get Wordpress installed on Arch Linux via the [Wordpress Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wordpress) and with [Apache and php-fm/mod_proxy_fcgi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP#PHP).

I installed Wordpress through pacman to "/usr/share/webapps/wordpress/"

When I try to run "systemctl start httpd" I get an error. Running "systemctl status httpd.service -l" outputs:

```
httpd.service - Apache Web Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2014-11-19 03:48:11 EST; 26s ago
Process: 12633 ExecStop=/usr/bin/apachectl graceful-stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 13162 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 12463 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

systemd[1]: Starting Apache Web Server...
apachectl[13162]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-wordpress.conf:
apachectl[13162]: Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Web Server.
systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.`
```

"/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-wordpress.conf" contains:

```
Alias /testing "/usr/share/webapps/wordpress"
<Directory "/usr/share/webapps/wordpress">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymlinks
        Require all granted
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/srv/:/tmp/:/usr/share/webapps/:/etc/webapps:$"
</Directory>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed PHP? The documentation states : _Note: You will need to have Apache configured to run with PHP. Check the LAMP#PHP page for instructions._   Check the following link : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP#PHP

Comment: Yes, I have php 5.6.3-1, php-apache 5.6.3-1, php-fpm 5.6.3-1, php-mcrypt 5.6.3-1, and phpmyadmin 4.2.11-1 installed. It seems to only be an issue with Apache not understanding how to run the php_admin_value command that is defined in httpd-wordpress.conf. I configured files as directed through [phpmyadmin](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpMyAdmin) as well, but no change.

Comment: If I comment out:

Include conf/extra/httpd-wordpress.conf

from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf then I can start httpd successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using php with a fastCGI proxy or PHP-FPM, the PHP runtime is not longer embedded in the apache runtime process. This will improve performance of your Apache webserver and PHP, since processes are stored in memory separate from each other, even after the request is server.

However this does mean that php admin values can no longer be stored in the apache configuration, as is possible when running php within apache itself.

You can add a server wide open_basedir restriction by adding

```
open_basedir = "<insert path here>"
```

to your global php.ini file, usually stored at `/etc/php5/<runtime>/` where your runtime will either be fpm, fcgid, or something along those lines.

Additionally, if you have multiple websites on the same server, it is possible to use `.user.ini` files in the root directory of your website to set PHP values. Values set in the `.user.ini` file will override any set PHP from `php.ini` when allowed (see [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php))